# Embedding node.js in a Firefox extension and running a server in-browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, firefox-addon

I am trying to figure out how to embed node.js within a Firefox extension, so that I can run a persistent server process (specifically [PeerServer](https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server)) from within the browser, as long as the user has the extension enabled. The only thing I've been able to find online is [this guide](http://rawkes.com/articles/running-node) ... but I haven't been able to make those instructions work, and need to find some more resources.

1) Does anyone have any other resources besides the article I linked to above that talk about embedding node.js in Firefox extensions? Any code examples?

2) Is there some reason that it would not be possible to run a persistent server process such as PeerServer from within a Firefox extension? Are there some kind of limitations on extensions that would prevent me from being able to do that?

Comment: This question might be better suited on Server Vault:(http://serverfault.com/).
You likely won't get an answer on here.

Comment: Although I have great interest in this question as well.

Comment: Thanks. I felt that it was more suited to here because it is more of a software development question than a system administration question. But if I don't get an answer here, I'll give it a try over there.

Comment: I personally don't think it would be better in Server Fault. It's related to Firefox extension development and node internals. It's very specific and probably not possible so it might be hard to gather competent interest here but it seems rather on topic.

Comment: There isn't really a great place for this. It's a grey-area. But regardless of where it belongs I think you'll find a better answer on Server Vault/Programmers just because of the people that hangout there. I could be wrong. Programmers.stackexchange is a good bet for software development.

Answer (score 2):

You can just have the executable in a folder of your extension and have JS code in the extension launch that executable. Running an external executable is described in the resource you linked or [here at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIProcess).

Example copied from MDN:

```
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
                     .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFile);
file.initWithPath("myapp.exe");

var process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"]
                        .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
process.init(file);

var args = ["argument1", "argument2"];
process.run(false, args, args.length);
```

A bit more logic is needed to find the absolute path of the user's profile to derive the path of the application to launch but it's doable.

Now if you want to interact with node from the extension you could use HTTP requests as a means of communication.

It sounds a bit strange to embed node in Firefox though when Firefox itself has a JS engine at its core. A more elegant approach would be to try to get PeerJS running directly in Firefox addon context, without node. Maybe more complicated but it should be possible. See for example this addon "[Browser Server](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/browser-server/)".

Comment: the Browser Server link is dead. Do you happen to know if someone has implemented this in Firefox's WebExtensions system?

Comment: @freyley I'm interested in building something like this. Did you have any luck finding any more leads?

Comment: @sijpkes I went to a bunch of different mailing lists and eventually concluded that the WebExtensions framework makes this effectively impossible.