# Is it possible to embed a node.js server inside a Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, server

First, I wanted to post a comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291617/embedding-node-js-in-a-firefox-extension-and-running-a-server-in-browser) but I haven't enough reputation... so I start a new thread.

My question can sound weird but I really want to embed and node server inside a firefox extension. I know there is [this old project](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nodejs/) but as I understand, it uses soon to be deprecated XPCOM API so it's a no way for starting a new project.

I read about [native messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging) but it does not allow to embed the executable, so it's useless. The purpose of a browser extension is to simplify the installation process.

So if we can't embed a binary, are there equivalents to node.js API available for developers on the browser side ? It seems that the answer is no :(.

Can someone give me a little hope ?

Comment: um out of curiosity what are you trying to do?  in coding it is better to focus on "how do i solve ____" rather than "is this possible" questions.

Comment: `The purpose of a browser extension is to reduce the installation task for the user.` the installation task of _what_?

Comment: @sova I'm trying to make firefox "torrent aware" by give it the ability to click on the torrent or magnet link as we would click on a href in order to ease the use of torrents. For exemple, you want to download a linux distro, you click on the torrent and you can save the iso just like you'd done with a direct download link.

Comment: @vlaz : sorry if my sentence was not clear. I wanted to say : "to simplify the installation process". If people need to install a node server themselves to be able to use my webextension, it's useless...

Comment: @Andreas I think you can achieve what you wan through other methods.   Might consider looking at the source code for some firefox extensions that are open-source and do similar things.  I still don't really see how node fits in with what you want to do ...

Comment: @sova : I don't want Firefox to "transform" Firefox to a torrent downloader like transmission or µTorrent but I want it to "see" torrent links like just like any other html links. I want torrent download to be transparent, so I need a webserver which transform torrent content to an http stream. That's why I want to use node.js and torrent-stream.